# Are these vectors the same?

Tags: vectors

$r = 2j -k + \lambda(i +2j -3k)$

$r'= 5i +6j -10k +\mu(2i +4j -6k)$

If so, could you show me how they are equal

$i: 5 = \lambda $

$j: 6 = 2 + 2\lambda $

$k: -10 = -1 -3\lambda $

Seems like lambda's value are different so for me it doesn't look like they are the same line but the answer says it is.

Comment: Please show us what you’ve tried so far

Comment: Define things. Who are $i,j,k$? I think you are tallking about quaternions. And who are $\mu$ and $\lambda$? Real numbers, complex numbers? Are they arbitrary?

Comment: I substituted (5i, 6j, -10k) into the first equation and work out lambda but seems like it doesn't look like the same line. λ and μ are scalars and i,j,k are components.

Comment: The coefficients of $i,j,k$ must be equal. Compute & compare. For example, the $i$ component of $r$ is $\lambda$ and the $i$ component of $r'$ is $5 + 2 \mu$.

Comment: @tommy1996q $i,j,k$ are conventional names for the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. That seems like the most reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @tommy1996q: I think there is a less Hamiltonian explanation...

Comment: @Arthur Seems reasonable. Quaternions still scare my analytic heart in my nightmares, I see them everywhere :)

Comment: No, $i,j,k$ are unit vectors

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show what you've tried and you'll be more likely to receive positive replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first vector is $$<\lambda,2+2\lambda,-1-3\lambda>$$

The second one is $$<5+2\mu ,6+4\mu,-10-6\mu>$$

Solving for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ results in an inconsistent system.

There are no values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ to make them the same vectors.

Thus my answer is no they are not the same vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If so, then we have 
$$\vec{r}=\vec{i}\lambda+\vec{j}(2\lambda+2)+\vec{k}(-1-3\lambda)$$
$$\vec{r'}=\vec{i}(5+2\mu)+\vec{j}(6+4\mu)+\vec{k}(-10-6\mu)$$
so it would be $$10+4\mu+2=6+4\mu$$ so$12=6$ they are not the same.